# Have an issue with using interfaces from DTO

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, dto

I have folder dto in global level where I keep my interfaces, but when I want to get it on frontend I have problems. I Import DTO but can't use interfaces from there.

DTO

```
export namespace DTO {
  export interface IUser {
    id: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: number;
    country: string;
    speaks: ILanguage[];
    learn: ILanguage[];
    isOnline: boolean;
    isFriend: boolean;
    photoUrl: string;
  }
}
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "dto": ["../dto/index"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src", "../dto"]
}
```

In fontend I get It but can't use

```
import { DTO } from 'dto';

export interface Test extends DTO.IUser
```

but have an error

```
Parsing error: ',' expected
```

Comment: Your interface declaration statement is not complete, try `export interface Test extends DTO.IUser {}`

Comment: Thanks it is work when i do like you say!